# problem with sequence deployment

Tags: truffle

I followed this way of deploying contracts using truffle.

```
// Deploy A, then deploy B, passing in A's newly deployed address
deployer.deploy(A).then(function() {
  return deployer.deploy(B, A.address);
});
```

But my contract, despite showing as deployed in the truffle console, is not recognized by my web3js code.

It works if i deploy the two contracts seperatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
deployer.deploy(A).then(function(a) {
  return deployer.deploy(B, a.address);
});
```

or with async/await (better readability):

```
deployer.then(async () => {
    var a = await deployer.deploy(A);
    var b = await deployer.deploy(B, a.address);
    // ...
});
```